# BibTex not working with TexMaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm using TexMaker, but it doesn't read my .bib file.

Here is a sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello. \cite{nobody99}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

And here is my sources.bib file:

```
@article{nobody99,
author = {nobody},
title = {ciao},
year = {1999}
}
```

I'm using this compilation sequence : PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex (x2) + ViewPDF

I have tried in many ways to make it work, but it doesn't. The log file appears like this:

> LOG FILE :
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.8) 13 AUG 2019 17:42
>   entering extended mode
>   **./ciao.tex
>   (ciao.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>   ("C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
>   Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   ("C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
>   File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
>   )
>   \c@part=\count80
>   \c@section=\count81
>   \c@subsection=\count82
>   \c@subsubsection=\count83
>   \c@paragraph=\count84
>   \c@subparagraph=\count85
>   \c@figure=\count86
>   \c@table=\count87
>   \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
>   \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   \bibindent=\dimen102
>   ) (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test\build\ciao.aux)
>   \openout1 = `ciao.aux'.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
>   LaTeX Warning: Citation`nobody99' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
>   No file ciao.bbl.
>   [1
>   {C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
>   (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test\build\ciao.aux)
>   LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
>   )
>   Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   207 strings out of 492895
>   2487 string characters out of 3123736
>   59667 words of memory out of 3000000
>   4206 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
>   3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
>   1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   23i,4n,22p,114b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
>   
>   Output written on C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test\build\ciao.pdf (1 page, 21001 b
>   ytes).
>   PDF statistics:
>   14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
>   0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>   1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

What am i doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What does the `.blg` file say? What exactly do maean with ‘does not work’?

Comment: Yes, sorry, "does not work" in this case means that the reference appear as [?] in the pdf and that I get a "citation nobody99 on page 1 undefined" in the message log.

There is no .blg file

Comment: Is the bibliography present, yet?

Comment: the log shows you ran pdflatex, but have you run bibtex?

Comment: The .bib file is in the same folder as the .tex file. I tried to compile manually with `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex`, but nothing. I also tried to compile the .bib file alone using `bibtex`.

Comment: And what does `bibtex` say during the manual run?

Comment: if you run `bibtex ciao` then it will generate a `.bbl` file with your bibliography, or leave an error in the `.blg` bibtex log saying why not.

Comment: If I run with `bibtex` I get the log "Process started. I couldn't open file name `ciao.aux'. Process exited normally", but no .bbl nor .blg files.

Comment: Maybe the explanation in this question will help: [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852).

Comment: @matteeeo that is strange, when you run `pdflatex` for the first time the `ciao.aux` file is supposed to be generated. Can you check if the file is actually there after the first `pdflatex` run? Maybe it is a problem with file permissions, the files belong to an Admin account that might be inaccessible to `bibtex` for some reason?

Comment: @Marijn the .aux file is actually there, and I checked that it was created right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem: I had the option for using a "build" subdirectory for output files active. Once switched it off, the compilation went smoothly and the references were there.